# Why are we allowed to move over "dt" terms when solving separable differential equations?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

When solving the differential equation:

$\frac{dx}{dt}=x(t)'=f(x)g(t)$,

we manipulate it so that

$\frac{1}{f(x)}dx=g(t)dt \Rightarrow \int \frac{1}{f(x)}dx= \int g(t)dt$

But from what I understand, it's not strictly allowed to split the $dx$ and $dt$ terms in this manner, since you can't simply multiply the $dt$ term to both sides.

So then my instinct is to look at

$\frac{1}{f(x)}\frac{dx}{dt}=g(t) \Rightarrow \int\frac{1}{f(x)}\frac{dx}{dt}dt=\int g(t)dt$

But even in this case, are we allowed to just cancel out the $dt$ terms on the left hand side? My intuition tells me that $dt$ isn't a number, so you shouldn't be allowed to do this? Can someone explain what's happening here, and if you **are** allowed to just cancel them... why?

I guess the concept of being able to split up and cancel out $dt$ terms is relevant for the chain rule and U-sub as well, so even in these 2 cases, why are we allowed to cancel/split up these differential terms?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: This is a good but frequently asked question, see here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1356981/why-does-the-separation-of-variables-method-for-des-work

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's precisely the chain rule that says you can do this. Integration by substitution is justified by the chain rule. If $x=g(t)$, then $$\int_a^b f(g(t))g'(t)\,dt = \int_{g(a)}^{g(b)} f(x)\,dx.$$ Why? Let $F$ be an antiderivative of $f$; i.e., $F'(x) = f(x)$. Then
\begin{align*}
\int_a^b F'(g(t))g'(t)\,dt &= \int_a^b (F\circ g)'(t)\,dt = (F\circ g)(t)\Big|_a^b \\ &= F(g(b))-F(g(a)).
\end{align*}
That's precisely what $\displaystyle\int_{g(a)}^{g(b)} f(x)\,dx$ is.

Comment: That makes sense. I think what confused me was that in previous calculus classes, the chain rule was "proved" using the idea that "dt" terms can cancel out and move about. But then to show that the "dt" terms cancelling/moving around is fine, people use the chain rule. So it seemed like a circular argument, until I found a proof for the chain rule that didn't use any "dt" terms.

Comment: Well, that was no proof. Just heuristics.